# What is the solution for Error: Cannot find module 'yargs'

Tags: yarnpkg, yargs

Did the ff commands but still getting the error

run this command from powershell with admin previlages:
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

cmd:
npm i yargs --save
yarn add yargs

Answer (score 1):

`npm install --save @types/yargs`

This worked for me.